# Find if printers are capable of color printing

Tags: powershell, printing

So I've been tasked to get a report of all of our printers that can print in color. I've found a script from here (http://voices.yahoo.com/listing-printers-ips-using-windows-powershell-6617942.html?cat=15) which works great for about everything but not if its color.

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Printer -computer $printserver | Select Name,DriverName,PortName,CapabilityDescriptions
```

I thought 'CapabilityDescriptions' would work but this is based off the driver and we are using the HP Universal Printing PS.

So I double checked and in fact when on the printserver and going to the printer properties on the General tab under Features it lists 'Color'.

In fact a printer that is color says 'Yes' and one that isnt says 'No'

Now is there another type of variable to the powershell script I'm missing to find the Color 'Yes/No' of each printer?

Thanks!

Comment: So I've just found this command, but the 1 an 2 for color isnt reporting properly.


`Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PrinterConfiguration -computer printserver | Select Name,Color`

Any reasons why its not showing up correctly? Is this due to the Universal Driver?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version of PowerShell you are running and whether you have access to Windows 8 machine or not, but if you do, PrinterManagement module would help you, as it seems to correctly identify color printers (we use Universal drivers as well):

```
PS> get-printconfiguration -ComputerName $printserver -PrinterName $nonprinter

PrinterName     ComputerName    Collate    Color      DuplexingMode
-----------     ------------    -------    -----      -------------
printername       servername   False      False      OneSided

PS> get-printconfiguration -ComputerName $printserver -PrinterName $colorprinter

PrinterName     ComputerName    Collate    Color      DuplexingMode
-----------     ------------    -------    -----      -------------
printername       servername   False      True       OneSided
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to run this command but query ever printer on the print server?

Answer (score 0):

```
gwmi win32_printer -cn $printserver | select name,capabilitydescriptions
```

Is what I used.

Comment: This failed to run correctly on my machine.  Got the error:  Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty.

Answer (score -1):

In my environment somehow all the printers report Color: true even when they aren't. i found no entry anywhere on the server under the printer properties saying Color: Yes/True when they weren't color printers. (General / Features / Color: No, yet

```
Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName XYZ_BW_PRINTER_1

PrinterName     ComputerName    Collate    Color      DuplexingMode       
-----------     ------------    -------    -----      -------------       
XYZ_BW_Printer_...                 False      True       OneSided
```

(and same result with every existing command there is)

Why is that happening?

Comment: Please post questions as actual questions, not as answers to another question. Also - not sure if you realized, but you posted this to a question from almost 9 years ago.